# Using javascript code in HTMLQuestion

Tags: amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

I am using javascript code inside an HTMLQuestion form to validate the user input .

```
<HTMLQuestion  xmlns="http://mechanicalturk.amazonaws.com/AWSMechanicalTurkDataSchemas/2011-11-11/HTMLQuestion.xsd" >
<HTMLContent>
 <![CDATA[
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
 <head> 
  <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'/>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script language = "javascript"  type='text/javascript' >
      $(document).ready(function()
      {
          alert("iFrame is ready");
      });
  </script>
```

sadly i am not getting the javascript code working. I tried to track the html code and it turned out that Each hit will be impeded as IFrame. It looks like Amazon Mechanical Turk disallow imbeded javascript code

Comment: Two options: (1) Javascript is allowed but the cross-domain script might be the issue; (2) use an ExternalQuestion and host on your own server to avoid this problem.